# Extract Data From Table Based on Multiple Criteria within ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a problem that I would like someone to help me with.

I need to cross data from a table, the table is the following below:

[image]

Literally I want to put in the "Yellow" line the amount I want, it can be any one from 0 to 3000. If in "Yellow" put for example 190, which is up to 200, then it will select column F. If you put 1000, then will already select column H.

Then I need to cross data with the lines, which will be up to x m2. That is, if in the line where it says "Green" select for example 0.3. Then it will select line 15. The Result of the 2 questions would be 1000 in this example.

However, I've already made a few attempts, and there I arrived at a formula killer:

```
=IFS(AND($E$20<=$F$14;$E$21<=$E$15);$F$15;AND($E$20<=$F$14;$E$21<=$E$16);$F$16;AND($E$20<=$F$14;$E$21<=$E$17);$F$17;AND($E$20<=$F$14;$E$21<=$E$18);$F$18;AND($E$20<=$G$14;$E$21<=$E$15);$G$15)
```

And this formula continues until the end. It's effective, it does its job, but in addition to being huge, it also makes it difficult to edit one day. I would like to try to improve it.

Any idea?

I apologize to everyone who was confused by my earlier attempt to explain my problem. Thank you all.

Comment: Which are you actually interested in?  And you forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the expected output in Km2 for the values provided? Is it a calculation to carry out or a value to find in the previous table?

Comment: What is the significance of the quantity? Are the values of m2 and Km2 calculated? If so, what is the calculation?

Comment: @ScottHunter. Im interested in getting the values that are not in bold. Example: If the quantity is 200 and M2 is 4. Then the result is 1400. My atempt to solve this problem, I know how to get a value to cross if the cell is the exact value, but when I have to get the value if is up to x m2, then I dunno how to solve it.

Comment: @DavidLeal. If I insert 200 in quantity it should search in the first column, lets say it is column A. Then when I insert the M2, example, 12. It is more than 10 and less than 15. It should give me the value 900.

Comment: @RGilchrist. Quantity are the values in bold. 200, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000 and 3000. M2 are the values in bold: Up to 5m2 (1 to 5), Up to 10 m2 (6 to 10), etc etc. When I insert this 2 values it should give the cell that corresponds in the column and line. Like a matrix in a crossed value.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you don't use text in column A (is that column A?) But numbers. 5 10 15 etc. Then you could use MATCH or (X)LOOKUP.

Comment: Cannot post an answer as this was closed, but if you already know how to cross find the value, if all the "up to" values will be multiples of 5 you could just use [`=CEILING(x, 5)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093471) to round the `y` axis to the nearest multiple. You will also need to use something like a [`REGEXEXTRACT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) to pull the numbers from the text.

Comment: @soldcarvalho please update the question with all the context provided and clarification in the comments, submit it for review so it can be opened again (be aware it can take sometime)

Comment: Hello, I updated the question @Daniel. Any idea how to improve this formula?

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding you are looking for two match criteria. For yellow criteria you look for exact match and for green criteria, the exact match or the next upper value.

You can use `INDEX/XMATCH` for that as follow using `LET` function in cell `J3`:

```
=LET(rng, B2:G5, upper, 1*TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A2:A5, " m2"), " ", -1),
  INDEX(rng, XMATCH(J2, upper, 1), XMATCH(J1, B1:G1))
)
```

or without `LET` function:

```
=INDEX(B2:G5, XMATCH(J2, 1*TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A2:A5, " m2"), " ", -1), 1),
 XMATCH(J1, B1:G1))
```

**Note**: The above approach doesn't require a helper column with the `upper` values, if such information is provided like in the updated version of the question (column `E`), then use the corresponding range instead.

Here is the output:

[image: excel output]

It assumes there is a space between `m2` and the number in the green column. You need to standardize it in your input. For example the last green row doesn't have a space. If that is not the case you need to cleanup it first, via `SUBSTITUTE` function for example or manually it seems to be a typo.

The name `upper` contains the number associated to `m2` in the green column using `TEXTBEFORE` and `TEXTAFTER`. The first `XMATCH` uses the third input argument (`1`) to ensure if the value doesn't exist, then it finds the next upper value. The second `XMATCH` look for an exact match for the yellow column.

This is a well known use case: Two dimensional lookup or two way lookup. For example you can check: [INDEX XMATCH XMATCH to perform 2-dimentional lookup](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-xmatch-function/#index-xmatch-xmatch) and just to adapt it to your specific case. You can also use `XLOOKUP` function for similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do it the way you showed me. However, I don't use excel and therefore I don't have this "LET" formula.
I had to improvise.

Followed this way:

[image]

I made a new column with the intended values.
All these values would be approximate, for example, if I put 150 in quantity and say that they are 5m2, it would give me the result of 1400. This is because it is below 200 units and below 5m2. Another example, if you put 499 units and put 13m2, then the result would be 360,

Currently, with this formula, I have already achieved approximations. However, the values are not matching up and when I pass 1500 units then it gives me this error: The value of Parameter 2 of the INDEX function, 5, is out of range.

Have a good year David.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).